# No image display from kml file in Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to load a `kml` file into my google maps app. I'm using this code to load it: code

The code works right, it load the `kml` file, but then when I clicked on some points, the images doesn't display, seems it like that:

[image: Image not loading]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my url photo contain "*" and it doesn't load the url from there.